# How to manually load UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uikit

I kind of have a weird layout here, it's kind of like this (also see pics):

-UITableViewCell 1

----UIView 2

--------UITableView 3

The controller the the UITableView (1) is like that:

```
    //mainTableView (1) controller

var cellHeights = [CGFloat]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let card = CardSource.orangeCards[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCardInCell(card)
    cellHeights.insert(card.frame.height + 15, at: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath.row]
}
```

but the problem is that when the screen first loads, the UIViews overlap because the cells are too small because the smaller table view (the one in the UIView) hasn't loaded yet and it's height isn't defined. Proof of this is that when I scroll to the bottom of the main table view then scroll back up cellForRowAt is called again and the two views don't overlap anymore (see pics). So what I basically want is a way to load the small table view and define it's height before the bigger table view loads (or if you have any other solutions, that'd be welcome too)

I know my question isn't very clear, I'm not really good at explaining stuff, so don't hesitate to ask me questions in the comments.

Many thanks!

[When the view first loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgjUN.png)

[After scrolling down then back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcaSB.png)

EDIT:

I found this:

```
    static var pharmacyOrangeCard: CardView {
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Pharmacy Orange Card", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PharmacyTableCardView
    print(view.frame.height)
    return view
}
```

prints the correct height. But then, when I try to access it from the controller above, it gives me a smaller number! In the meanwhile, I applied these constraints:

```
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 35).isActive = true        
    card.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    card.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

But I don't think that affects height, does it?

EDIT 2:

Okay, so I've changed this constraint:

```
self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 35).isActive = true
```

to this:

```
    card.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 17.5).isActive = true
    card.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -17.5).isActive = true
```

So these constraints seem to play a role because now I have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6RqC.png)

By the way, I don't know if that matters but I'm using XIB files for each of these "cards", and the height isn't constrained, so maybe that plays a role?

SOLVING EDIT:
I solved the problem by doing:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    mainTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing `card.layoutIfNeeded()` before `cellHeights.insert(card.frame.height + 15, at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: Yes, configureCardInCell() has layoutIfNeeded() at the end

Comment: But you are saying that `card.frame.height` is still wrong at that point?

Comment: Yes, please see edit, something very strange is happening

Comment: Why are you using `cellHeights.insert(card.frame.height + 15, at: indexPath.row)` so `card.frame.height` instead of `cell.frame.height`?

Comment: Because I want the cell to have a height of card.height + 15

Comment: If width and height are in a ratio or otherwise dependent on each other then `self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 35).isActive = true` can make the height smaller. Try printing the height if you do not subtract 35, ``self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true` (I know that is not what you desire as far as design, but we are just trying to see if the height will be correct)

Comment: Nope, still doesn't do it :/ I'm going to try to pin it to the sides instead of having this constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a cell loaded on the screen, you cannot change height for that cell for better UI-Experience,

and in hierarchy heightForRowAt get called before cellForRowAt.

So you had 2 options to choose for a solution to your problem

- first:: get your heights values ready before your table view try to loads cells in it (get heights array ready before setting delegate and datasource values to your tableView)
- second:: whenever you need to update your tableView cells to re-established with respect to new height values, call this each time after you have updated your height values

  *yourTableView.reloadData()*